Modelling stocks with jump to default and recovery value
Jump to default models (eg Black-Scholes or SV with jump to default) are quite tractable models to model the possibility of default.
However, if a company defaults it doesn't always mean the stock price goes to zero. The company could be restructured for example.
I was wondering if it makes sense to then model such a stock as a shifted lognormal with jump to default, where the constant or deterministic value in the shifted lognormal represents the stock recovery value / the minimum value the stock price can have.
Any suggestions from practitioners in this field?

Note that a company can default only if it has debt to default on.  This makes most modelers interested in jump-to-default's effects across the entire capital structure.  You therefore find treatments particularly in convertible bond modeling.  In those models, equity conditional on default is essentially always given a point probability and that is almost always zero.  But, like Enron, companies can disappear for other reasons than debt.  Not sure how you would choose hazard rates for that.

@BrianB True. Basically I'd be happy if I could approximate default and recovery rates from equity options and if those approximations are in line with what is implied by the bond(s) and/or single name CDS.
